# Regex Pandas in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have my column of my dataframe `df['data']`.

For each line of this column data i want to verify if the string of each line contains any of:

```
risque de fraude, risques de fraude, risques de frodes, fraud risk, fraud,fraude, frode,fraudes, frodes
```

If the line contains one of these strings return 1.

How can i do it using regex?

Thank you

Comment: Check `.str.contains()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.str.contains` with a regex:

```
df['new'] = df['data'].str.lower().str.contains('risque de fraude|risques de fraude|risques de frodes|fraud risk|fraude|frode|fraudes|frodes').astype(int)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Would result in a dataframe with an additional column, `'new'` having the expected `0` and `1` integer values.

Comment: thank you .. how can i deal with ( F or f )in the beginning of fruades and frodes.. because with this expression i cant detect Fraude with capital F.. Thank you so much

Comment: @ena Try now, don't forget to accept it if it is good.

Comment: Hello !! please how can i do to not detect "fraudation" for example.. I want if i have "fraudation" it doesn't return anything and with this expression it return 1